# How to Implement read-only user using ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES in RDS Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Team, I would like to implement read-only permissions in RDS PostgreSQL ( e.g. ver: 10.15 ), I tried the following but i couldn't query the tables after successfully executing ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILGES statement. I wanted to achive this - whenever user admin_user001 create schema, tables, sequence and function in that specific database, the readonly user "read_user01" should get readonly permission on those schemas and objects.

Step1: user setup

```
a. CREATE ROLE admin_role with INHERIT LOGIN password 'Password123#';
   grant admin_role to rdsmasteruser;

b. CREATE USER "admin_user001"  WITH PASSWORD 'Password123#'  INHERIT CREATEDB  valid until 'infinity';
   CREATE USER "read_user01"  WITH PASSWORD 'Password123#'    INHERIT valid until 'infinity';
   grantadmin_user001 to admin_role;
   grant read_user01 to admin_role;

c. CREATE role readonly with INHERIT LOGIN password 'Password123#';;
   grant readonly to read_user01;
```

Step2: Execute ALTER DEFAULT comamnd

d. admin_user001 create new database called "proddb01"

e. rds master user connects this new datbase "proddb01" and execute these comamnds:

```
comamnd1: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for role admin_role GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO  readonly; 
comamnd2: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for role admin_role GRANT SELECT  ON TABLES    TO readonly;
comamnd3: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for role admin_role GRANT SELECT  ON SEQUENCES TO  readonly;
comamnd4: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for role admin_role GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO  readonly;
```

note: I dont want to pass the schema name in any of the abvoe ALTER DEFAUT comamnds, the first comamnd1 wil work for major version 10.x and above, it may not work for 9.x as per Postgresql documentation, so, if version is < 10.x then  I can grant USAGE permission on schemas seperately using GRANT statement, I am good on this. So, I would like to run the first comaamnd1 for 10.x and above. this test rds postgresql instance version is 10.15

Step3: Schema & tables in proddb01

d. admin_user001 create schema called "schema01"
admin_user001 creates one table called "table01" ( within schema01 )

Step4: Access validation for rds master user and admin_role

e. Connected proddb01 as rds maser user and checked this sql query: select * from schema01.table01;    ---it worked

Connected proddb01 as admin_role and checked this sql query: select * from schema01.table01;        ---it worked

Connected proddb01 as role "readonly"  and checked this sql query: select * from schema01.table01;        ---it failed

```
***ERROR:  permission denied for schema schema01***
```

then I manually granted schema permission to this role readonly and tested same query select * from schema01.table01; ---it failed

```
***ERROR:  permission denied for relation table01
```

My observation: ALTER DEFAULT commands did not grant the permission to target role "readonly". Below is the output of default permissions granted

```
rdsmasteruser@rdspostgres1015 12:54:26@proddb01=#\ddp
                   Default access privileges
   Owner    | Schema |   Type   |       Access privileges
------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------
 admin_role |        | function | =X/admin_role                +
            |        |          | admin_role=X/admin_role      +
            |        |          | readonly=X/admin_role
 admin_role |        | sequence | admin_role=rwU/admin_role    +
            |        |          | readonly=r/admin_role
 admin_role |        | table    | admin_role=arwdDxt/admin_role+
            |        |          | readonly=r/admin_role
 admin_role |        |          | admin_role=UC/admin_role     +
            |        |          | readonly=U/admin_role
(4 rows)
```

Question: In the above example, I created a role called "admin_role" ( with INHERIT )which is member of all the other datbase roles,so,admin_role has the ability to access the objects/schemas created by any other datbase users/roles. Can I use this admin_role in the FOR ROLE clause in the ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILGES command ? I would like to pass one role name (in this FOR USER clause) which should have access to all the objects created by all the users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with objects created by `admin_user001`, you have to create default privileges `FOR ROLE admin_user001`. Role membership is not enough.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thank you for your comment, I would like to pass one role name which should be member of all the other database roles, in this case it is admin_role, but it did not work. I am not sure whether this is possible or not. The option that you suggested will work for sure, however, I need to pass a role name which has control on all the objects created by all the users at any point of time ( kind of proxy user ). Thank you

Comment: As I said, if the privileges should be granted when user `x` creates a table, then you must use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE x`. It's as simple as that. Role membership doesn't count.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, this is the answer that I was trying to get earlier and created this topic. this helps a lot Laurenz. So, I will pass all the database users in the FOR ROLE clause and cut the read-only permission to group readonly. I close this thread. Thanks again.